# Extract list out of Option[List] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the below list:

```
val list: Option[List[String]] = Some(List("one","two","three"))
```

However I want the list to be the same but without the option, so that it looks like this:

```
val changedList = List("one","two","three")
```

However I'm new to scala and cannot figure out how to do this!
Grateful for any help!

Comment: `val changedList = list.getOrElse(List())`

Comment: You should also consider how you are going to use this list once you have extracted it. You might be able to process the list while it is still in the `Option`. For example you can test the contents with `exists` or `forall`, you can modify the list with `map` or `collect`, you can process the list using `foreach`, and you can extract a derived value using `fold`. In general it is good to keep the `List` in the `Option` as long as you can because this is the best way to handle both the `Some` and `None` cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two solutions (which have exactly the same length, strangely enough):

```
list.toList.flatten
```

gives the same result as

```
list.getOrElse(Nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

`getOrElse` method from Option is enough.

```
list.getOrElse(List.empty[String])
```

I strongly recommend avoiding Pattern Matching in this case, since it's a lot more procedural than getOrElse.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is `Option[T]` you can pattern match it to `Some` or `None`,

```
scala> val list: Option[List[String]] = Some(List("one","two","three"))
list: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(one, two, three))

scala> list match {
     |    case Some(nonEmptyList) => nonEmptyList
     |    case None => List.empty[String]
     | }
res0: List[String] = List(one, two, three)
```

Or, shorter way is to use `getOrElse`,

```
scala> list.getOrElse(List.empty[String])
res1: List[String] = List(one, two, three)
```

Found simple example [Option in Scala, University of Pennsylvania](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cis554-2011/Pages/scalas-option-type.html)
 which could be useful

Answer (score 0):

`.get` will work for you

```
val list: List[String] = Some(List("one","two","three")).get
```